# Multiple commands to Restore,Synch,Attach,Create database or Alter database

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

Backup and restore errors: Multiple commands to Restore,Synch,Attach,Create database or Alter database with name='XXX' or ID='XXX' that doesn't exist on server yet are working concurrently. Current transaction is aborted.

[image]

> Root Cause : the cube database deleted while sync from stage to live and we cannot new database with the same name.

My workaround is restart SSAS service and it works.

But **do we have some geek way to list and kill the cube sync process and refresh the cube cache?**
**How to do that?**

Answer (score 1):

Not work with DMV Queries.

Any way just restart SSAS service? since the issue can only happened in stage server. the restart won`t affect production live cube.

But if much stage cube with running command in the same stage server, .. Best Wishes.